# How to quickly pick a random file from a folder-tree?

Tags: c++, performance, file, random

I'm trying to pick a random file from a folder tree, starting from a fixed path and "searching" recursively across all subfolders (or the choosen folder itself).

My idea is: make the list of files, calculate the number of files, choose a random number in this range and than pick the file at that index.

Here's my code:

```
// create list of all files
std::vector<std::string> paths;

for (const auto &entry : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(mPathDirectory)) {
    if (!std::filesystem::is_directory(entry)) {
        paths.push_back(entry.path().string());
    }
}

// pick random file
size_t numberOfFiles = paths.size();
int indexRandomFile = (int)round(rescale(random::uniform(), 0.0, 1.0, 0, numberOfFiles - 1));

return paths[indexRandomFile];
```

Also with `O3`, its pretty slow, considering I've a huge list of files and I'm inside an "audio" application (which should be faster).

Do you have any smarter ideas? Somethings like O(1)? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know nothing about the folder structure, you have to recurse into it to find out how many items there are. There is no O(1) solution.

But an "app" needs to only *feel* fast, i.e. it's often only the perception of responsiveness that matters. To that end on first start you can employ heuristics, like recurse into *some* subfolders with a certain probability, until you find *a* file. It will not be uniformly random, but it will be relatively arbitrarily chosen from the user's standpoint.

Meanwhile you can *really* recurse into the folders and build up a *cache*, while the initially selected file is already playing.

Answer (score 6):

Choosing a file uniformly at random this way can be done using the [*reservoir sampling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) technique. For each file, choose it at a 1/N chance, where N is the number of files you found so far, including the file just found. The random file is then the last file chosen this way.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56927252/what-is-the-best-way-to-randomly-pick-a-record-line-from-a-txt-or-csv-file-every/56938218) for the similar task of choosing a random line from a text file; reservoir sampling applies, in general, whenever the number of items to choose from is not known in advance.

---

The following explains how reservoir sampling works:

1. Set N to 1.
2. Set ChosenFile to null.
3. For each file:

   - If `random::uniform() < 1.0 / N`, set ChosenFile to the file's name.
   - Add 1 to N.

Now, ChosenFile is the randomly chosen file name.

---

Taking the code in your question, here is how reservoir sampling can be implemented. Note that no files are stored in a list anymore. Note also that this code is untested.

```
// store randomly chosen file
std::string path;
size_t n = 1;

for (const auto &entry: std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(mPathDirectory)) {
    if (!std::filesystem::is_directory(entry)) {
        if (random::uniform() < 1.0 / n) {
           path = entry.path().string();
        }
        n++;
    }
}

return path;
```

Comment: But how can I pick a file from a number/index? I need a list to start with...

Comment: Your question (in your question post) doesn't speak of choosing a random file from _its index_ (other than as one way of choosing a random file from a directory).  Reservoir sampling doesn't require you to store the names of all the files you find in the process of choosing one of them at random.  In any case, I will edit this answer to explain better how reservoir sampling works.

Comment: Is the "for each" file the problem. Iterate over huge amount of files makes the task slow. Thats my problem...

Comment: Are you saying that `recursive_directory_iterator` is itself too slow for your purposes?  Do you notice a significant difference in running time by storing and not storing each file name in a vector?

Comment: What would you store over the file name? Pointer? Not sure...

Comment: Run the code in your question by commenting out `paths.push_back(entry.path().string());`, then run the code again by not commenting out that line.  (This is only roughly what it takes to test the running time difference.)  Do you notice a significant difference in running time between the two runs?  Also, in case you need some extra clarification on how to implement reservoir sampling, I have edited my answer.

Comment: The real "heavy" code is `std::filesystem::is_directory(entry)`. If I remove it, I pass from 5 seconds to few ms. Wow... I'll try to improve it better hahah

Comment: Still I don't get why this Algo should be better. I mean: it will iterate "each file" in any case. Isn't that the heavy part? Also: is the random number choosed once at the beginning? Or it Need to change at each iteration?

Comment: A different random number is chosen in each iteration.  Also, you can stop iterating at any time (say, after 500 iterations), and the random file name will then be one chosen uniformly from among the file names then seen.   In any case, to choose a file at random, you have to know that it exists -- this is something that no random selection strategy can change.  However, if you need to choose a random file name repeatedly from the same selection of file names, such as to shuffle them, it's better to store them in a list for this purpose (as you're doing now) rather than use reservoir sampling.