# Select random folder from directory (not file)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, random

What I am trying to do is to make my program randomly pick a folder from a directory and read the slots.csv file inside. All of the folders have the slots.csv file, it's just that the folders are named differently. I understand how to use `random.choice(os.listdir("C:\\"))` but I can't seem to get it to work with folders...

```
import os, random

random_centre = random.choice(os.listdir("Centres" + "\\" + postcode))
df = pandas.read_csv(r"Centres" + "\\" + postcode + "\\" + random_centre + "\\" + "slots.csv")
```

I keep getting the same error,

`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'Centres\\31400'`

Comment: What's the error? That looks like it should work.

Comment: I see you've been asking a lot of questions here, and are working your way through this project of yours.  I don't know if you've read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, but try to show us what it is you are dealing with... try to take all the guess-work out of it for us... we'll be able to help you better.

Comment: I actually have made mention of my project in one of my other posts. I'm currently building a vaccination appointment program that is fully automated. My folders are named using postcodes. This piece of code on this thread will randomly pick a vaccination centre from a folder that is synonymous with the user's postcode. Also, i'll take your advice and provide more detail on what i'm doing with if I have any more questions and turn these series of questions into a proper thread for people building similar-type programs.

Comment: Well, it says it cannot find either or just the post code folder, 31400, or even the Centres folder. Verify both exist.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58400066/how-to-quickly-pick-a-random-file-from-a-folder-tree/58400187?r=SearchResults&s=1|37.0090#58400187

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Pandas, so here's a mock-up using Python's CSV module.

My number-one suggestion is to use `os.path.join()` for assembling your paths.  Even though I'm on a Mac, this code should work on your Windows machine because the `join()` method takes the OS into consideration when picking the path separator.  That's probably not your issue, but it'll make your code a little cleaner.

As for the random question, your code looks like it should work:

```py
import csv
import os
import random

postcode = '12345'
base_path = os.path.join('Centres', postcode)
random_centre = random.choice(os.listdir(base_path))
csv_path = os.path.join(base_path, random_centre, 'slots.csv')

with open(csv_path, newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    print(csv_path)
    print(list(reader))
```

Here's what it looks like when I run this a couple of times:

```
% ./main.py
Centres/12345/b/slots.csv
[['Col1', 'Col2'], ['Val1', 'Val2']]

% ./main.py
Centres/12345/a/slots.csv
[['Col1', 'Col2'], ['Val3', 'Val4']]

% ./main.py
Centres/12345/a/slots.csv
[['Col1', 'Col2'], ['Val3', 'Val4']]

% ./main.py
Centres/12345/b/slots.csv
[['Col1', 'Col2'], ['Val1', 'Val2']]

% ./main.py
Centres/12345/a/slots.csv
[['Col1', 'Col2'], ['Val3', 'Val4']]

% ./main.py
Centres/12345/c/slots.csv
[['Col1', 'Col2'], ['Val5', 'Val6']]
```

Comment: Thank you Zach, but, even with the addition of the line, ` base_path = os.path.join('Centres', postcode) ` , I keep getting the same error over and over. ` FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'Centres\\31400' `

Comment: Correction: Even with the usage of the lines `base_path = os.path.join('Centres', postcode)` and `random_centre = random.choice(os.listdir(base_path))` , I still get the same error

Comment: Okay, put that error up top in your post.

Comment: Are you sure you're running it from the right directory? Perhaps you are looking for the file in /home/user/ instead of the actual path. Do a print(os.getcwd()) to see where you really are. Or test with os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Centres', postcode)

Comment: @cyber101 you were right, I had not gotten my directory right. My apologies, and thank you

Comment: No worries - happy coding!